# Cant import ssl key to cacerts keytool

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl, certificate

I have a file with certificates and I want to add a new SSL certificate to it by using `keytool` command.

How do I add the `trust.jks` file to the `cacerts` file?

I am trying to use something like this:

```
keytool -importsert -file</usr/ssl/trust.jks> -keypass<567890> -keystore -file</usr/sert/cacerts> -storepass<12387461324>
```

But I have a syntax error.

Comment: Use it like `keytool -importcert -file</usr/ssl/trust.jks> -keypass <567890> -keystore -file </usr/sert/cacerts> -storepass <12387461324>`

Comment: This is not a programming question and @Ananthapadmanabhan is still wrong. If trust.jks is in fact a JKS (i.e. a keystore) _containing_ certs, use `keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore /usr/ssl/trust.jks -destkeystore /usr/sert/cacerts` to import/copy its contents. Add `-{src,dest}storepass $pw` if you don't want to be prompted, but if you are on a multiuser system (less common today) or run untrustworthy software, this allows other users to see your passwords. Put a space between each `-option` and its value and never use `< >`.